# Any music industry sound designers here?

Tags: music, industry

I have read mostly about sound designers in film or video games. Has anyone here professionally had a career designing for producers, artists, software companys, hardware companys?

Answer (score 1):

I just made a non-traditional violin based sample library for VIR2.  Lots of acoustic preparations and odd playing techniques as well as tons of interesting digital manipulation.

http://www.vir2.com/instruments/violence

I'm currently working on another library but this one is going to focus more on acoustic preparations.

I have a blog where I document some of my musical sound design experiments.  Although recently I've been busy doing film work have neglected to post much but you may find some of the older articles interesting.

http://www.brendanjhogan.com/blog

Comment: those look like some rad samples @violence

Comment: and just listened to them, they are hella rad!